# Wrap text within element LXML

Tags: python, lxml

I have html-code some like this

```
<body>
  <p> String </p>
  Some string
</body>
```

I need to wrap all unwrapped text inside a body with a paragraph.
I can do it with javascript Node.nodeTypes, but i need solution on Python (i try to use lxml).

In output i need

```
   <body>
      <p> String </p>
      <p> Some string </p>
    </body>
```

My solution on javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('article').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue).length;
  }).wrap('</p>');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <p>Some text</p>
  Some unwrapped text
  <p>Some text</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how it can be done using lxml:

```
html = '''
<html>
<body>
  Text
  <p>String</p>
  Tail
  <p>String</p>
  Tail
</body>
</html>
'''

from lxml import etree
import lxml.html
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

for doc_child in doc:
    if doc_child.tag == 'body':
        body = doc_child
        if body.text and body.text.strip():
            p = etree.Element('p')
            p.text = body.text.strip()
            body.text = None
            body.insert(0, p)
        for elem in body:
            if elem.tail and elem.tail.strip():
                p = etree.Element('p')
                p.text = elem.tail.strip()
                elem.tail = None
                elem.addnext(p)

print(lxml.html.tostring(doc).decode('utf8'))
```

Output:

```
<html>
<body><p>Text</p><p>String</p><p>Tail</p><p>String</p><p>Tail</p></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `BeautifulSoup` module to parse html pages.
- There were many ways available to do this.

But this is one of the easiest method to parse html to text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <p>Some text</p>
  Some unwrapped text
  <p>Some text</p>
</article>'''
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
print parsed_html.text
```

Output:

```
Some text
Some unwrapped text
Some text
```

Comment: but i need html on output (no simple text)

Comment: Please can you elaborate your question with sample output.?

Answer (score 0):

Python, with `lxml`:

```
from lxml.etree import fromstring
body = fromstring("""
    <body>
      <p> String </p>
      Some string
    </body>
""")
for text_node in body.xpath("//text()"):
    parent = text_node.getparent()
    if text_node.strip() and parent.tag != "p":
        wrapper = fromstring("<p/>")
        parent.replace(text_node, wrapper)
        wrapper.append(text_node)
```

Comment: this never enters the if statement